# Replace file/directory name with text given from user input

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

I'll preface this by saying that I am not a programmer at all. I am a video editor and post-production consultant that is interested in making tedious tasks simpler or maintaining uniformity across all file/folder structures on each project.

I have managed to cobble together a few .bat scripts to serve the purposes that I need, but on this particular one I've hit a bit of a roadblock and Google searches have been somewhat helpful, but mostly have led to more confusion.

I have a batch file to create project directories and template files whenever we have a new project.

It asks the user to input first the Project Number and then the Project Name.

Then it makes all the necessary directories and copies files & folders from a template folder to the newly created project folder

All this works flawlessly to this point.

But, I now want the template folders and files that it just copied to be renamed with the %number% the user entered earlier.

In my mind, it should be a simple matter of

***find any instance of "[project number]" in the project folder just created and replace it with %number%***

But I can not figure out how to make this work.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the script that I have so far (note: I've removed superfluous bits to reduce the amount of clutter for the purpose of sharing it here)

```
@echo off

echo >>SOME INSTRUCTIONS THAT THE USER WILL SEE<<

set /p number="Enter Project Number ONLY (ex. 21-000): " 
set /p project="Enter Project Name ONLY (ex. Test Project): "

MkDir "W:\2021-ASSETS\%number%_%project%-ASSETS\%number%-Adobe Projects\%number%-AE Projects\" 

PAUSE

copy "W:_GENERIC-Assets_Generic Templates\AE Project Template\[project number]-yymmdd.aep" "W:\2021-ASSETS\%number%_%project%-ASSETS\%number%-Adobe Projects\%number%-AE Projects\"

PAUSE

xcopy "X:_FILES for new projects" "X:\Projects\2021 Projects\%number%_%project%" /e

PAUSE
```

---

This is where I am getting stuck.

The "_FILES for new projects" folder contains a file/folder structure that have names like "Audio-[project number]", "Graphics-[project number]" and so on. I want to have this final part of the script find all instances of [project number] (regardless of whether it's a file or directory) and replace it with the %number% the user input at the start.

I know I can use something like Bulk Rename Utility, but I was hoping to make the renaming a part of the script to make sure it was done consistently. The people who will be using this are not very technical and at times reticent when it comes to making changes to things, so the simpler it is for them the better. The interface of Bulk Rename Utility is very cluttered and overwhelms them as they don't know if they're doing it correctly. Plus, it adds an extra step to our project creation process that could get omitted by mistake.

Thanks in advance for your help/advice.

Also note, PowerShell is not an option. Someone helped me out on reddit and provided me with a PS script, but the company's IT policy flagged/blocked it and wouldn't let me test it. IT said they could provide an exception for me to run it, but it also means that I would be the only person on our team with access to run the PS script. That's not an option.

Comment: The first advice I'd offer is to spend much more time improving your code to validate your users input. Taking account that your end user can currently type nothing or anything at all at each prompt, _(including misunderstandings, typimg errors, and malice)_, and that `%number%` will be expanded in multpile locations nested within a tree. I'd suggest it is essential that you do.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "targetdir=u:\your files"

rem constant strings

SET "projectnumber=[project number]"

rem data that has been entered

SET "number=12345"


FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /s "%targetdir%\*%projectnumber%*" '
 ) DO (
 SET "namestring=%%~nxa"
 SET "newnamestring=!namestring:%projectnumber%=%number%!"
 ECHO REN "%%a" "!newnamestring!"
)
```

Please note the use of `delayedexpansion` which allows `!var!` to access the value of the variable `var` as it changes during the execution of a `for` loop. Note that `%var%` accesses the value of `var` at the time the loop is encountered. There are many, many SO articles about this - just use the `search` facility.

The `for` loop analyses a `dir` listing of all files and directories found under the directory defined as `targetdir` that match the name-mask `*%projectnumber%*` = that is, contain the string defined as `projectnumber` which has previously been established.

It is standard practice on SO to use the syntax `set "var=value"` for string
assignments as this ensures stray trailing spaces on the line are ignored. In the case of your `set /p`, use, eg `set /p "project=Enter Project Name ONLY (ex. Test Project): "`.

The `delims=` option ensures that the entire file/directoryname is assigned to `%%a` (the `metavariable`.

The **N**ame and e**X**tension part of the value in `%%a` (%%~**NX**a) is then assigned to the variable `namestring` since the next step must be applied to a variable, not a metavariable.

Calculate newnamestring by setting it to the *current* value of `namestring` (`!namestring!`) but after replacing the string defined as `projectnumber` (`%projectnumber%`) with that defined as `number`.

Then `ECHO` the required `ren` command. `Ren` renames a file or directory, but the new name may contain only the name and extension parts - not the drive and path.

So, after running this code, you'll find it issues a report to the screen of the *renames* it intends to do. This is a safety measure for manually checking that the commands are appropriate. If all seems according to Hoyle, delete the `echo` keyword and the rename will be applied.

Note: batch is generally case-insensitive, so the **NX** can be in any case. The only common exception to this is the metavariable `a`, which must be consistently in the same case to refer to the same metavariable.